# How to pass a array object to an oracle stored procedure?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, python-oracledb

how to pass the array object?

Here I have connected the Oracle DB through Python by using the Oracledb library

#DB connection

```
connection = oracledb.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb")
```

```
#cursor object
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

#declare a output variable

```
 out_values = cursor.var(int)
```

here i need to pass the pass the values to oracle stored procedure

```
array_values = ['u','U','G']
  cursor.callproc('schema.pkg.get_prc',[array_values ,9713979, '2', '2', 'N'])
```

above array_values I need to pass the array object.how to pass the array object?

"errorMessage": "ORA-06550: l: wrong number or types of arguments in    call to 'get_prc

below are the stored procedure

```
 **schema.pkg.get_prc**(pt_enrol_data IN  tb_enrol_matching,
  p_enrol_log_id IN  NUMBER,
  p_columns IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_dynamic_columns IN  VARCHAR2)
  
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE schema.tb_enrol_matching
  IS OBJECT
  
  Email  VARCHAR2(4000),
  Forename  VARCHAR2(4000),
  Lastname VARCHAR2(4000),);
```

how to pass the array object and call the stored procedure i dont know the problem is, I believ. Thanks in advance.`

Comment: `tb_enrol_matching` is not an array; it is an object.

Comment: You want to look at [sections 7.11 and 7.12 of the Python OracleDB documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-spatial-data-types) if you want to pass objects to the database. If you want to [bind arrays then you want section 7.9](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-pl-sql-collections) (but, as already mentioned, you aren't passing an array).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes it is an object, we need to pass the as array object, 
below I'm calling the proc, here how will pass the array object, could you please example?

array_values = ['u','U','G']

cursor.callproc('schema.pkg.get_prc',[array_values ,9713979, '2', '2', 'N'])

Comment: Your procedure takes 4 arguments and you are passing 5 values.

Answer (score 2):

Your data-type of the column in the database is **NOT** an array; it is an object. Therefore you do **NOT** want to pass an array from python; you want to pass an object.

See the ["7.12. Changing Bind Data Types using an Input Type Handler" documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind). Which gives the example:

> ```python
> # A standard Python object
> class Building:
>
>     def __init__(self, build_id, description, num_floors, date_built):
>         self.building_id = build_id
>         self.description = description
>         self.num_floors = num_floors
>         self.date_built = date_built
>
> building = Building(1, "Skyscraper 1", 5, datetime.date(2001, 5, 24))
>
> # Get Python representation of the Oracle user defined type UDT_BUILDING obj_type = con.gettype("UDT_BUILDING")
>
> # convert a Python Building object to the Oracle user defined type
> # UDT_BUILDING def building_in_converter(value):
>     obj = obj_type.newobject()
>     obj.BUILDINGID = value.building_id
>     obj.DESCRIPTION = value.description
>     obj.NUMFLOORS = value.num_floors
>     obj.DATEBUILT = value.date_built
>     return obj
>
> def input_type_handler(cursor, value, num_elements):
>     if isinstance(value, Building):
>         return cursor.var(obj_type, arraysize=num_elements,
>                           inconverter=building_in_converter)
>
>
> # With the input type handler, the bound Python object is converted
> # to the required Oracle object before being inserted cur.inputtypehandler = input_type_handler cur.execute("insert into
> myTable values (:1, :2)", (1, building))
> ```

Change `Building` to match the structure of `TB_ENROL_MATCHING`:

```python
class EnrolMatching:
    def __init__(self, email, forename, lastname):
        self.email = email
        self.forename = forename
        self.lastname = lastname


ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE = connection.gettype("TB_ENROL_MATCHING")


def enrol_matching_in_converter(value):
    obj = ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE.newobject()
    obj.EMAIL = value.email
    obj.FORENAME = value.forename
    obj.LASTNAME = value.lastname
    return obj

def input_type_handler(cursor, value, num_elements):
    if isinstance(value, EnrolMatching):
        return cursor.var(obj_type, arraysize=num_elements,
                          inconverter=enrol_matching_in_converter)


cursor.inputtypehandler = input_type_handler
cursor.callproc(
    "schema.pkg.get_prc",
    (EnrolMatching("u", "U", "G"), 9713979, "2", "N"),
)
```

*Note: this is untested as I do not have your tables or procedure to test against but you should get the general idea of how to implement it.*

If you wanted to simplify it to the bare minimum code then:

```python
ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE = connection.gettype("TB_ENROL_MATCHING")
enrol_matching = ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE.newobject()
enrol_matching.EMAIL = "u"
enrol_matching.FORENAME = "U"
enrol_matching.LASTNAME = "G"
cursor.callproc("schema.pkg.get_prc", (enrol_matching, 9713979, "2", "N"))
```

*Note 2: Again untested for the same reasons.*

Comment: could you please help me, I have followed the same code, but I'm facing an issue like 
`ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE = connection.gettype("TB_ENROL_MATCHING")
enrol_matching = ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE.newobject()
enrol_matching.EMAIL = "u"
enrol_matching.FORENAME = "U" `

` "errorMessage": "'EMAIL'",
 "errorType": "KeyError",
  line 38, in handler\n    enrol_matching.Email = \"u\"\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/oracledb/dbobject.py\", line 53, in __setattr__\n    attr_impl = self._impl.type.attrs_by_name[name]\n" `

Comment: `ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE = connection.gettype("TB_ENROL_MATCHING")` print(ENROL_MATCHING_TYPE) `<oracledb.DbObjectType HOT_ENROL.TB_ENROL_MATCHING>`